# Order by elements based on input text, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to order a list of items in anguarjs based on an input text, so if i write in my input "author" the list will be ordered by author

my code is this

```
<input type = "text" ng-model = "sort">

<ul class = "list-unstyled">
 <li ng-repeat = "comment in dishCtrl.dish.comments | orderBy: sort">
            <blockquote class = "blockquote">
               <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars </p>
               <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
            <footer>{{comment.author}}, {{comment.date | date}</footer>
            </blockquote>
 </li>
```

It doesnt work, I already searched but can't find this kind of example.

Answer (score 5):

You have to define the variable in the controller:

```
var sort = '';
```

Then you have to define the ng-model directive to bind the input value to this variable:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dishDetailCtrl.sort">
```

And then you can apply the filter:

```
<div class="well" ng-repeat="comments in dishDetailCtrl.dish.comments | orderBy: dishDetailCtrl.sort">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very tiny mistake in your code. There should be no space after `orderBy` expression.

```
<li ng-repeat = "comment in dishCtrl.dish.comments | orderBy:sort">
```

<s>If above doesn't work try, putting it in single quotes like `'sort'`</s>

Comment: thanks, i didnt think a space would cause my program not to run correctly

Comment: I faced this space issue a lot of times. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need bind an action on this input it can be simple ng-enter directive or a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using controller as syntax, as i can see from your ng-repeat, change

```
<input type = "text" ng-model = "sort">
```

to

```
<input type = "text" ng-model = "dishCtrl.sort">
```

And also update your ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat = "comment in dishCtrl.dish.comments | orderBy: dishCtrl.sort">
```

Comment: Hi, it works now, thanks a lot, i tried it in that way and like the person below me said, thanks a lot