# AngularJS custom order by with function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I get the value of a input text and compare with a value of an object with an array?

When I type the property name of the comments array, has to order by this text that was typed.

For example type author order by author.
I search about this, read documentation but I didn't find a solution.
Can i pass a function in the order by? I try but didn't work.

I found too many example passing just one value or without the input text and I wanna pass 3 options to order, if author, rating or date, but if someone type this words in the input text.

Why doesn't work like this:

```
Sort by: <input type="text"  ng-model="**sortBy**">
                   <div ng-repeat="dishcomment in dishCtrl.dish.comments|filter:**sortBy**">
```

---

```
 var dish={
     name:'Uthapizza',
     image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
     category: 'mains', 
     label:'Hot',
     price:'4.99',
     description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
     comments: [
         {
             rating:5,
             comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
             author:"John Lemon",
             date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
         },
         {
             rating:4,
             comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
             author:"Paul McVites",
             date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
         },
         {
             rating:3,
             comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
             author:"Michael Jaikishan",
             date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
         },
         {
             rating:4,
             comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
             author:"Ringo Starry",
             date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
         },
         {
             rating:2,
             comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
             author:"25 Cent",
             date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
         }
     ]
 };

 this.dish = dish;
```

```
Sort by: <input type="text"  ng-model="searchBox">
           <div ng-repeat="dishcomment in dishCtrl.dish.comments | orderBy:searchBox track by $index">
             <blockquote> 
                <p>{{dishcomment.rating}} Stars</p>
                <p>{{dishcomment.comment}}</p>
                <small>{{dishcomment.author}}
                {{dishcomment.date | date:'MMM.dd, yyyy'}}</small> 
             </blockquote>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454658/ng-repeat-orderby-object ?

Comment: unless I misunderstand the question completely, this is functional as written:  http://plnkr.co/edit/poU4KXsy9GZFeLjnnsZ6.  Typing `rating` causes the order to change, as does typing `comment` or `author`.

Comment: It's not what a have in mind. I just wanna call a function that receive the value of the input and check if was one option order ng-repeat.

Comment: against which property you want to check the textbox content?

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom filter in angular as below :

```
app.filter('commentsFilter', function ($filter) {    
    return function (inputArray, orderBy) {
    var outputArray = [];

    if (order) {
        angular.forEach(inputArray, function (input) {
           if(orderBy === 'author'){
                // Sort by author logic goes here
                // Modify outputArray with sorted data
           }
          if(orderBy === 'date'){
               // Sort by date logic goes here
               // Modify outputArray with sorted data
           }                
        });
    } else {
        return inputArray;
    }
    return outputArray;
   };
});
```

HTML code snippet is as below

```
Sort by: <input type="text"  ng-model="searchBox">
       <div ng-repeat="dishcomment in dishCtrl.dish.comments | commentsFilter:searchBox track by $index">
         <blockquote> 
            <p>{{dishcomment.rating}} Stars</p>
            <p>{{dishcomment.comment}}</p>
            <small>{{dishcomment.author}}
            {{dishcomment.date | date:'MMM.dd, yyyy'}}</small> 
         </blockquote>
       </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I find a simple way to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100705/order-by-elements-based-on-input-text-angularjs/38962231#38962231                                                 Just assingning a string empty solve the problem. And if I wanna a funtion works to but without ()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of HTML filters we can try putting filters on the controller code and update the list on ng-change of the input.
This will be:

1. easier to understand.
2. Will be better for large list as the number of watchers created will be lot less than the html filters.

   ```
   $scope.sortBy = function(){   
   if($scope.dish.comments.hasOwnProperty($scope.sortByProp)){

       //sort the comments by the property
       $scope.dish.comments = sortedComments;

   }}
   ```

Following is the HTML snippet:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="sortByProp" ng-change="sortBy()">
```

Comment: Thanks. I found a way to do with orderby, works without ().